# how to transform xml with xslt preserving <br /> tags in a text

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt

I want to transform (with jquery.xslt.js) xml to be preserving tags in text nodes.
Xml looks like:

```
<example>
   <text>
      Some text with <br /> and <img src="source" /> then text ....
   </text>
</example>
```

I want to have:

```
 <div class="example"> 
  <p>Some text with <br /> and <img src="source" /> then text ....</p> 
 </div>
```

If I use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` I'll get

```
 "Some text with and then text ...."
```

If I add `<xsl:apply-templates />` I'll get

```
"Some text with and then text .... <br/><img src="source" />"
```

Is there any way to exact rewrite content of tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/example/text">
  <div class="example">
    <p>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
    </p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```